# Get content between tags using TinyXML

Tags: c++, tinyxml, xml

How can I get content between tags

```
<name>  </name> and <mode> </mode>
```

---

```
<news>
    <name>Enter</name>
    <actions>
      <mode>me</mode>
    </actions>
   </news>
```

Comment: What code have you tried, what problems did it have, and what do you think will work?

Comment: I solved the peblem with the help of this post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really have a look at the excellent [documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html) of TinyXML as well as [the tutorial](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html). However, what you are looking for is the [`GetText()`](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlElement.html#b1436857d30ee2cdd0938c8437ff98d5) method of TiXmlElement.

Once you've arrived at your "name" or "mode" elements, you can get the string between these tags with `GetText()`.

Answer (score 1):

\ this

```
TiXmlDocument doc("tes.xml");

   if (doc.LoadFile())
  {
     TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
   TiXmlText* text = hDoc.ChildElement("news", 0).ChildElement("act-news", 0).ChildElement("name", 0).FirstChild().Text();
if(text)
{
const char* message = text->Value();
cout<<(message)<<endl; 
 } 

TiXmlText* stext = hDoc.ChildElement("news", 0).ChildElement("act-news", 1).ChildElement("name", 0).FirstChild().Text();
if(text)
{
const char* message = stext->Value();
cout<<(message)<<endl;
```